# Filtering a line out of a string c#

Tags: c#

I want to read a .txt file in c# and filter a line out of the string and only show that line. If the match is on the first line, i get a good output using streamreader.ReadLine. But if it's on the second line, i need to get it filtered. (i tought by creating a ReadLine loop?)
Thanks in advance

```
        private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text);
        string BoxLM1 = sr.ReadLine();

        if (comboBox3.Text == "Anderlecht")
        {
            if (BoxLM1.Contains("Anderlecht"))
            {
            label5.Text = BoxLM1;
            }

            else
            {
                string BoxLM2 = sr.ReadToEnd();



                    MessageBox.Show(BoxLM2);  

            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check all lines at once using [`File.ReadLines()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) method and LINQ:

```
var firstAnderlecht = File.ReadLines(textBox1.Text).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Contains("Anderlecht"));
if (firstAnderlecht != null) {
    label5.Text = firstAnderlecht;
}
```

The `ReadLines` produces an enumerable of lines from the file; the `FirstOrDefault` method lets you apply a condition to all lines of the file without a loop, and pick the first line where the condition applies.

Comment: *`But if it's on the second line, i need to get it filtered`*

Comment: @L.B I think this refers to the OP's implementation, essentially saying that his code works for the first line already, but he needs to get it working for the second line and so on.

Comment: +1 for ReadLines. But you need to set `BoxLM1` to `.First(s => s.Contains("Anderlecht")`, otherwise it's still pointing at the first line.

Comment: The file saves football matches, listed as.
Lierse - Kv Mechelen 2 - 0
Anderlecht - Bergen 1 - 0

now i want label5 to show the last match Anderlecht played, If it's on the first line of the .txt, my code understands it, but if it's on the 2nd, i can only get it to show the wrong match.

Answer (score 0):

If you are manipulating big files i recommend to use this iterator:

```
private static IEnumerable FileIterator(String filePathe)
    {
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePathe))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                yield return line;
            }
            yield break;
        }
    }
```

it will prevent the loading of full file to RAM